# Check if a line from a txt file is a substring of a filename using batch

Tags: batch-file, substring, string-comparison

i have a txt file with several lines, now i want to check if a line is a substring of a filename. this is my code so far

```
for /r D:\ %%y in (*.*) do (
    for /f %%x in (list.txt) do (
        echo %%y|find %%x >nul
        if errorlevel 1 (echo notfound) else (echo found)
                )
        )
```

the first loop gets the filename while the second loop gets the lines from the txt file. now i know that the format for FIND is wrong as you need to define the string that you want to find but i want to show what i want to achieve. i want to check if %%y contains %%x. so how do i achieve that? thank you for any suggestions and sorry if my explanation is a bit hazy :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
FOR /f "delims=" %%k IN (filename.txt) DO DIR /s /a-d *%%k* 2>NUL >NUL &IF ERRORLEVEL 1 (ECHO %%k NOT found) ELSE (ECHO %%k found)
```

Read each line from the file. Perform a `dir` trying to find that filename anywhere in the subtree (`/s` for subdirectories, `/a-d` for no directorynames, `2>nul` to suppress `file not found` messages, `>nul` to suppress the report) setting `errorlevel` 0 for found and non-0 for not found.

Comment: thank you for your help but may i know if i want to search filename from specific filetype for example only check .jpg file

Comment: Use `*%%k*.jpg` as the filemask